# Emacs manuals are missing on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: help, info, ubuntu, debian

I was expecting the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual at (<kbd>C-h i m elisp</kbd>). But there was no menu `elisp` or `lisp` there. `C-h v` and `C-h f` work fine for variables or functions though. `C-h i 5` takes me to file permissions.

What other binding is standard to find something like [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html)?

Is that something that has to be installed?

Comment: `Elisp` (not `elisp`) works for me

Comment: Are you on Debian? I think the manuals need to be installed separately there.

Comment: @npostavs: yes on debian.

Comment: @Ves: neither one, nor the other.

Comment: You'll probably want to install this package: https://packages.debian.org/sid/emacs-common-non-dfsg Debian has a policy against GNU FDL, and they put Emacs' documentation into a separate package in `non-free`.

Answer (score 19):

This is a great question!

I've found the directions online to install it by hand unclear and, frankly, a bit of a pain (at least on Debian).

## On Debian...

Emacs on Debian doesn't come with the *Emacs Lisp Reference Manual* by default. It's [kind of silly](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsManualLicense), but Debian [stores it in the non-free repos](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/emacs25-common-non-dfsg).  Unfortunately, a regular `apt-get install` doesn't *Just Work™*.

*Note:*  Before proceeding, I assume you've installed Emacs from an official Debian mirror and not compiled from source or installed from some random `.deb` from some random dude on the Internet.

To begin, you need to [include non-free repos](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Component).  Do this by appending `non-free`<sup>1</sup> to the end of each entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, like

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main non-free
```

You'll need to run `sudo apt-get update` to refresh the package listing.

Once you've updated the package listing, install the package `emacs-common-non-dfsg`, like

```
sudo apt-get install emacs-common-non-dfsg
```

Note that older releases of Debian or Ubuntu may not have `emacs-common-non-dfsg`; in those cases, you'll need to add the Emacs version number, i.e.,

```
sudo apt-get install emacs25-common-non-dfsg
```

You may need to restart Emacs, or close and restart the Emacs info-browser.

## Manually installing...

I have not tested this, but it also ought to be possible to just point Emacs to the appropriate file.  The source is called `elisp.info` and is [available at gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html).  You'll want the "Info document" link.  Check `C-h v Info-default-directory-list` to see where the default `Info` directory is.  You ought to be able to either place the `emacs.info` file there or add another directory to the `Info-additional-directory-list` with

```
(add-to-list 'Info-additional-directory-list "/path/to/my/info")
```

You can [read more about the info path on the EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPath).

<sup>1</sup> **DISCLAIMER:** Although the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual is [libre](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html), including non-free repos does open you to [non-free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Free_Software_Guidelines).

<sup>2</sup> This [should](https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-nonfree-amd64/emacs25-common-non-dfsg_25.1+1-1_all.deb.html) install the *Emacs Lisp Reference Manual* as `emacs.info.gz` to `/usr/share/info`.  Strictly speaking, it seems like `dpkg` is the only [dependency](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/emacs25-common-non-dfsg), but I couldn't get Emacs to recognize the new contents in `/usr/share/info` without [install-info](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/install-info).  Maybe someone could clarify why, but that's more a Debian question than an Emacs one...

Comment: I don't think you need to install `install-info`, it will be installed automatically as a dependency. You can get the current manuals with `emacs-common-non-dfsg`, which will link to the latest manual; `emacs25-common-non-dfsg` will link to the emacs25 manuals, even if you are using a newer version.

Comment: `install-info` is a dependency of `emacs-??-common`. The command `install-info` is required to update info/dir entires (probably called by install scripts)

Comment: @jue Yes, that's correct. All I meant was that the command `apt-get install emacs-common-non-dfsg` is enough, as `apt-get` will automatically install any dependencies, including 'install-info`.

Comment: @jue I don't mean my comments as a criticism of the answer, I just wanted to update a few things since I'm recommending other questions are a duplicate of this one. (ie https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54349/how-do-i-install-an-introduction-to-programming-in-emacs-lisp?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Tyler thanks for clarifying the install steps.  No offense taken!  I don't have time to update my response atm.  If you've confirmed the steps, feel free to edit my answer.  Otherwise I'll probably get to it when I update to Buster.

Comment: @Tyler I just wanted to share my knowledge. :)

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu
1. Download https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/info/elisp.info.gz to your /usr/share/info directory.
2. From a terminal run update-info-dir command.
3. From emacs C-h i m Elisp (capital E).