# How do I install An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: help, ubuntu

This may sound odd, but when I type `C-h i m Emacs Lisp Intro` -- it's not there. I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 with Emacs 26.3. I tried `apt-get install emacs-lisp-intro` as the EmacsWiki said, but there's no such thing in the Ubuntu world. How can I get it installed?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Ubuntu user, on Debian this Elisp intro come from emacs-common-non-dfsg.   I think that should do it :   https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&keywords=emacs-common-non-dfsg

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But is there another way? My Ubuntu version of it is a bit out of date.