# How can I have the lighter of a minor mode be colored /propertized)?

Tags: mode-line, minor-mode, text-properties

How can I colorize/propertize the lighter of a minor mode in the mode line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the manual:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Properties in Mode`

Or in the online manual (which is always for the most recent stable release of Emacs): https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Properties-in-Mode.html

I think there's no point in quoting an excerpt here -- you need to read the whole page.

Comment: This is the answer. But please consider summarizing briefly what that node says that answers the question.

Comment: I get `user-error: Info file elisp does not exist`

Comment: If you don't have the manuals then you have an incomplete installation of Emacs.  The common way I know of for that to happen is if you are using a Debian-based GNU/Linux distribution (e.g. Ubuntu), as they split Emacs into multiple packages, and do not include the documentation by default.  If this describes you, then refer to:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48211/454

Comment: Drew: I don't think there's a useful way to summarize this one -- people should read the whole page, so I've edited the answer to say this.

Comment: I solved. Thanks!